# Delete image by filtering tags in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a filterable gallery. But the removing part is not working correct. I would like to remove all the images which are not similar to the entered word. I think the for-loop does not iterate in the right way. Every time I search for one tag in the gallery more than one appears.

Maybe someone got an idea what's wrong here.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "tags": "Haus",
        "imageName" : "image0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "tags": "Auto",
        "imageName" : "image1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "tags": "Baum",
        "imageName" : "image2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "tags": "Fluss",
        "imageName" : "image3.jpg"
    },
];

data.map(item => {
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('src', item.imageName);
    image.setAttribute('id', item.id); 
    image.setAttribute('class', 'image');
    image.setAttribute('name', item.tags);
    const container = document.getElementById('box');
    container.appendChild(image);
});

function getInputValue(){
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
    var l = images.length; 
    
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if(images[i].name != inputVal){
            console.log(images[i]);
            images[i].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="searchBar">
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <button onclick="getInputValue()">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing I see going wrong is using `map` for side effects. `map` is used to transform an array to another array; you are expected to use the transformed array, or you've wasted cycles and memory creating a new array. In this case, you can use `forEach` or a simple `for` loop. For the problem you're trying to solve; simply use `filter` on the `data` array and recreate the images using the `forEach`-instead-of-`map` you set up earlier, plus some clearing logic (`innerHTML = ""` works well).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you delete the image completely from the HTML. The best way to solve your requirement is to work with CSS styles.
Regardless of how you load your images into the HTML via jQuery, here is a working example.

For a better and more user-friendly search, it is best to use [toLowerCase](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) and [include](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

```js
var $searchInput = $('#input-search');

$('#btn-search').on('click', filterImages);

function filterImages() {
  var searchValue = $searchInput.val(),
    $images = $('.image');

  for (var i = 0; i < $images.length; i++) {
    console.log($images.eq(i));

    if (
      searchValue != '' &&
      //$images.eq(i).attr('name') != searchValue
      !$images.eq(i).attr('name').toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      $images.eq(i).css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $images.eq(i).css('display', 'block');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#box .image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchBar">
  <input type="text" id="input-search" />
  <button id="btn-search">SEARCH</button>
</div>
<div id="box">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/60x40/000000/FFF/png" id="0" class="image" name="Haus" />
  <img src="https://placehold.co/60x40/000000/F00/png" id="1" class="image" name="Auto" />
  <img src="https://placehold.co/60x40/000000/0F0/png" id="2" class="image" name="Baum" />
  <img src="https://placehold.co/60x40/000000/00F/png" id="3" class="image" name="Fluss" />
</div>
```